# LazyVim removal/uninstall guidance

Tags: neovim, lazyvim

I installed LazyVim and have a bunch of missing things with it so I want to know how do I remove it and go back to just default Neovim so I can build it back up from scratch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you have to remove the content of:

- `~/.config/nvim` (On Linux or MacOs)
- `~\AppData\local\nvim` (On Windows)

To be sure you can also delete the following folder:

- `~/.local/share/nvim` (On Linux or MacOs)
- `~\AppData\local\nvim-data` (On Windows)

Comment: wow it worked, you commented on one of my posts last night so sorry for not being that self sufficient, I just started learning to code like a week ago and have not been enjoying vs code so I want to learn something like neovim. Thank you for your help I greatly appreciate it very much.

Comment: Welcome to Vim! Thanks for the feedback :-) Don't worry we are all learning. If the solution address the problem maybe you could accept it using the v green button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to [lazy vim readme page](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim) in order to uninstall lazy.nvim, you need to remove the following files and directories:

- **data**: `~/.local/share/nvim/lazy`
- **state**: `~/.local/state/nvim/lazy`
- **lockfile**: `~/.config/nvim/lazy-lock.json`

> Paths can differ if you changed `XDG` environment variables.